# Why do I get a negative number by multiplying two short ints?

Tags: c++, c, type-conversion, implicit-conversion

I had an assignment where i had the following code excerpt:

```
/*OOOOOHHHHH I've just noticed instead of an int here should be an *short int* I will just left it as it is because too many users saw it already.*/

int y=511, z=512;

y=y*z;

printf("Output: %d\n", y);
```

Which gives me `Output: -512`. In my assignment I should explain why. So i was pretty sure it is because of the implicit conversion( correct me if I'm wrong:) ) happening from assigning an `int` value to an short int. But my tutor said that thing just happened called something with "triple round" i guess. I couldn't find anything about it and I'm watching a this [video](https://www.udemy.com/lectures/lecture-2-programming-paradigms-14788) and the guy explains(25:00) almost the same thing I told my tutor.

### Edit:

Here is my full code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {

    short int y=511, z=512;

    y = y*z;

    printf("%zu\n", sizeof(int));
    printf("%zu\n", sizeof(short int));

    printf("Y: %d\n", y);


    return 0;
}
```

Here is how i compile it:

```
gcc -pedantic -std=c99 -Wall -Wextra -o hallo hallo.c
```

I get no errors and no warnings. *But* if i compile it with -Wconversion flag enabled as follows:

```
gcc -pedantic -std=c99 -Wall -Wextra -Wconversion -o hallo hallo.c
```

I get the following warning:

```
hallo.c: In function ‘main’:
hallo.c:7:7: warning: conversion to ‘short int’ from ‘int’ may alter its value [-Wconversion]
```

So the conversion does happen right?

Comment: It's technically undefined behaviour if those are 16-bit ints, which you seem to imply with your short int comment.

Comment: What size is `int` on your platform?

Comment: This [cert document on signed overflow](https://www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/display/seccode/INT32-C.+Ensure+that+operations+on+signed+integers+do+not+result+in+overflow#INT32-C.Ensurethatoperationsonsignedintegersdonotresultinoverflow-Multiplication) may be helpful.

Comment: @0x499602D2 4byte and short int 2byte

Comment: @chris but if i have a -Wconversion flag when i compile i get conversion warning from int to short int I'm using gcc 4.6.3 on ubuntu linux

Comment: @orustammanapov The question title says *multiplying two short ints* but the code shows you're multiplying two `int`s. Which is it? If the title is accurate, then the two operands are being promoted to `int`s for the multiplication and then the result is truncated to a `short int` during the assignment to `y` as CarlNorum explains below.

Comment: @Praetorian I've updated my question, is it right know or was i wrong?

Comment: Ask your tutor to give you a reference to an explication of "triple round".  I've never heard of it (and there is no rounding involved with integral arithmetic except in the case of division.)

Comment: @JamesKanze thanks I sure will:) I was worrying because I've googled and couldn't find anything either.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The conversion from `int` to `short int` is implementation defined.  The reason you get the result you do is that your implementation is just truncating your number:

```
  decimal  |         binary
-----------+------------------------
    511    |       1 1111 1111
    512    |      10 0000 0000
 511 * 512 | 11 1111 1110 0000 0000
```

Since you appear to have a 16-bit `short int` type, that `11 1111 1110 0000 0000` becomes just `1111 1110 0000 0000`, which is the two's complement representation of `-512`:

```
 decimal |     binary (x)      |         ~x          |    -x == ~x + 1 
---------+---------------------+---------------------+---------------------
   512   | 0000 0010 0000 0000 | 1111 1101 1111 1111 | 1111 1110 0000 0000
```

Comment: I have 4byte (at least sizeof prints 4) and 2byte  short int

Comment: Not according to the output you're giving here, you don't.  Is your example not accurate?

Comment: that is the same thing I've told my tutor(that it gets truncated) and what about this "triple round" thingy ever heard about?

Comment: I have no idea what a triple round is.  Can you show your complete example?

Comment: I am very sure, that this answer is correct: for me this gives 261632 having 4byte integer, changing to short gives -512 exactly as it is logical and explained here.

Comment: If sizeof returns 4 then it should be 4 bytes.

Comment: I've updated my question. So you mean i do not get my bonus because of the thing that doesn't even exist?;(

Comment: thanks for help, nobody seam ever heard about the thing I also heard today first time in my life.

Comment: int promotion prevents this from being undefined behavior, given that he's multiplying 16-bit shorts and int is 32-bit. The value resulting  from the short->int conversion is implementation defined, however.

Comment: The result of a multiplication can require as many bits in the result as the sum of the number of digits from each multiplicand. E.g. multiplying a value that can be represented in 10 bits with a value that can be represented in 5 bits can result in a value requiring up to 15 bits. This is also true of other bases. If you think about the normal algorithm for multiplication it's clear why this is.

Comment: @barnes53 - yes.  OP's question had incorrect information when I first posted this answer.  I think I've corrected it now.